# Hibernate save succeeds alone but fails if run with few other tests

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm working on a project which is an assignment in a course I'm taking in the university.
In this project we are to implement an online forum system in a few iterations.
One of the requirements in this iteration is using ORM - we chose Hibernate and it's the first time we are experiencing it. so far we had a rough time :)

We're using intelliJ Idea 14, windows, java 7, mysql 5 and hibernate 4.2.

Among many classes we have POJOs that represent the domain layer and we have hibernateUtils which encapsulates the access to the DB, And a Junit class for testing it.

These are the annotated POJOs:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="user_id")
private int id;
@Column(name="name")
private String username;
@Column(name="email_address")
private String emailAddress;
@Column(name="password")
private String hashedPassword;
@Column(name="date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date creationDate;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="state")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private UserState state;
@Column(name="is_active")
private boolean active;
@Column(name="is_banned")
private boolean banned;
@Column(name="is_logged_in")
private boolean loggedIn;
@ManyToMany
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private Set<User> friends;
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="panding_notfications")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Notification> pendingNotifications;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "receivingMember")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private List<FriendRequest> friendRequests;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "reporter")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Report> sentReports;
@Column(name="seniority")
private int  seniority;
@Column(name="loginTime")
private long loginTime;
```

Forum:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Forum")
public class Forum {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="forum_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private User admin;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="sub_forums")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<SubForum> subForums;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="members")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<User> members;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="policy")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private ForumPolicy policy;
```

HibernateUtils:

```
public class HibernateUtils {

    private static Configuration cfg;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory =null;

    public static boolean configure(boolean init) {
        cfg = new Configuration()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Forum.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Message.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(SubForum.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Thread.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(ForumPolicy.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Report.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Notification.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(FriendRequest.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(UserState.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(UserStatusPolicy.class)
                .setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread")
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forum_system")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","root")
                .setProperty("hibernate.password", "");
        if (init) {
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        }
        sessionFactory = cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        return cfg!=null;
    }

    public synchronized static boolean start() {
        return configure(false);
    }

    public static boolean init() {
        return configure(true);
    }

    public synchronized static boolean save(Object o) {
        return saveReturnId(o) > 0;
    }

    public synchronized static int saveReturnId(Object o) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            int id= (int)session.save(o);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return id;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            ForumLogger.errorLog(e.toString());
            return -1;
        }
        finally{
            if(session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized static boolean del(Object o) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            session.delete(o);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            ForumLogger.errorLog(e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        finally{
            if(session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized static Object load(Class c,int id) {
        Object o=null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            o=session.get(c, id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            return  o;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            ForumLogger.errorLog(e.toString());
            return null;
        }
        finally{
            if(session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The part of the test class that we are currently running:

```
public class ForumTests {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void Setup() {
        HibernateUtils.start();
    }

@Test
public void testSaveForum() {
    Forum f = new Forum(new User(),new ForumPolicy(),"forum_name");
    int id = HibernateUtils.saveReturnId(f);
    Assert.assertEquals(f, (Forum) HibernateUtils.load(Forum.class, id));
}

@Test
public void testGetAdmin() {
    User u =User.newMember("asdsad","asd","sdkfdjk@sldkf.com");
    Forum f = new Forum(u,new ForumPolicy(),"forum_name");
    int fid = HibernateUtils.saveReturnId(f);
    Forum ormf = (Forum) HibernateUtils.load(Forum.class, fid);
    Assert.assertEquals(u, ormf.getAdmin());

}

@Test
public void testAddSubforumFromForum() {
    User u =User.newMember("user","pass","mail@gmail.com");
    int uid = (int)HibernateUtils.saveReturnId(u);
    Assert.assertTrue(uid>0);
/* commented out code */
}
```

When running each of the following tests separately they all succeed. But when running all of them we get this error: (In testGetAdmin test)

```
May 27, 2015 2:11:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
May 27, 2015 2:11:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`forum_system`.`forum`, CONSTRAINT `FK_l9pbqj2i36itiuhbu7q61xqlq` FOREIGN KEY (`admin`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`))
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

which I pretty much understand but i can't figure out why should that happen only when running all tests together? (maybe something about transactions?)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are stateful, i.e. they are changing the data and leaving it changed after they run.

That means that when the next test runs, the data isn't "clean" but has been poluted by the tests before it.

To fix this, make sure the individual tests clean up after themselves OR set up a clean environment before each test runs - At present you initialise hibernate once for the whole class

Comment: That's true but doesn't create the problem.
The primary key which is the id is auto-incremented and therefore, new rows are being created even if running the test twice creates (almost) the same row. Moreover, running each of the tests alone multiple times doesn't reproduce the problem, so obviously that doesn't affect on the outcome.

Comment: Running each test multiple times doesn't reproduce the problem as the state is only maintained for the duration of the test class. Even if that wasn't the case, it still wouldn't prove that it's not a statefulness issue (which it definitely is incidentally) because it may only occur on a certain combination of tests being run in a certain order.

Comment: Try changing the order of the methods around. If you do it enough, you'll probably hit a combination that works, although the test code will still be stateful and therefore prone to breaking in unexpected ways when other changes are made. Stateful tests of this nature are bad news.

Comment: Ok, so what will be the best (and fast) practice to make it stateless?

Comment: The fastest, in terms of work for you, is probably to have a Before method that starts up your HibernateUtils, and an After method that pulls it down. This may have an impact on the performance of the tests though, depending on how fast your HibernateUtils class is.

Comment: Shouldn't I delete the inserted rows in each test case?

Comment: That's certainly an option. I thought it may take you longer though. Ideally you'd reverse ALL changes made at the end of each test, and you'd also have remember to add code to do so for any new tests you add in the furture. If you use a Before and After method then it just works after that althgouh potentially at the cost of some performance. If your tests start with empty tables, then another option would be to have an After method that simply truncates the tables. That'd be a quick and effectice change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78940/discussion-between-phil-anderson-and-tom).